# MySQL timespan between two times calculation

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a project on a restaurant where I have put table reservation. I am having problem calculating the time span between two times. It should be like this:

If a person want to book table, he is putting a date and two times. I will have to check whether there are any booking in the time span between these two times. I have put the screenshot of my table structure with this question. Please help me.

[image: example]

(Full size image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnSyX.png).)

Comment: you can add the image in question itself

Comment: Would you like all of this work served with a side of mashed potatoes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from booking
where (user_from between (booking_time_from AND booking_time_to))
     or (user_to between (booking_time_from AND booking_time_to))
```

where `user_from` and `user_to` are user input time